# MPI program with compiling options to be serial and parallel

Tags: mpi

I've wrote an MPI program and could be paralleled in C++. I would like to make it optional to be compiled for parallel or serial. Take the following hello world program, what's the common practice to achieve that? I saw some software compiled with option --serial/--parallel, but not sure how exactly it was done.

MPI version:

```
#include <mpi.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);

    int numprocs;
    int procid;
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &numprocs);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &procid);

    printf("Hello world from process %d \n", procid);

    MPI_Finalize();
}
```

Serial Version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    num = stoi(argv[1]);
    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++){
        printf("Hello world from process %d \n", num);
    }
}
```

Comment: Keep in mind a MPI program can generally be ran as-is without `mpirun` (aka singleton mode), so unless you plan to execute the “serial” version on a node where the MPI runtime is not available, the simplest option could be to only build the parallel version. An other option is to use some MPI stub library so all you would need to build the serial version is to change your makefile (read no source code modification required).

Answer (score 1):

There are two levels in your question:

- First, you may want to compile the same source code with and without MPI, producing two different programs---one parallel, one serial.
- Or, you may want to compile one program (with MPI), but use command line option to specify whether the program is to be executed in serial or in parallel mode.

A code like the one below combines both.

If the first command-line argument is "-parallel", the program will start with the MPI initialization routine and terminate with the MPI finalization routine.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int iproc = 0;
    int nproc = 1;
    int par   = (strcmp(argv[1], "-parallel") == 0);
    int nwork = atoi(argv[2]);

    if (par) parallel_init(&argc, &argv, &iproc, &nproc);

    for (int i = 0; i < nwork; i++)
    {
        if (i % nproc == iproc)
        {
            printf("Running task %d by rank %d\n", i, iproc);
            /* ... etc ... */
        }
    }

    if (par) parallel_final();

    return 0;
}
```

Also, you can compile this source without the need for MPI at all by passing the `-DNOMPI` flag to the compiler.

```
#ifndef NOMPI
#include <mpi.h>
#endif

void parallel_init (int *pargc, char **pargv[], int *piproc, int *pnproc)
{
#ifdef NOMPI
    *piproc = 0;
    *pnproc = 1;
#else
    MPI_Init(pargc, pargv);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, pnproc);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, piproc);
#endif
}

void parallel_final ()
{
#ifndef NOMPI
    MPI_Finalize();
#endif
}
```

E.g.,

```
> mpicc main.c 
> ./a.out -serial 4
Running task 0 by rank 0
Running task 1 by rank 0
Running task 2 by rank 0
Running task 3 by rank 0
> mpiexec -n 2 ./a.out -parallel 4
Running task 0 by rank 0
Running task 2 by rank 0
Running task 1 by rank 1
Running task 3 by rank 1
```

Comment: Hi, @jacob, thank you very much. The second example you provided is exactly what I was asking for.